# алгоритм распределения входящих заявок между менеджерами

Tags: php, алгоритм, sqlite

Подскажите, каким образом обычно решается такая задача (php/sqlite):

В БД сайта записываются заявки на услугу от пользователей сайта. Эти **заявки нужно распределить по менеджерам. Крайне желательно распределить равномерно.**

Например: у меня 15 менеджеров (мен1, мен2, мен3, ..., мен15) в таблице "Менеджеры" моей БД.

Мне нужно каждую новую заявку, поступающую в таблицу "Заявки" БД, присвоить кому-то из менеджеров таким образом, чтобы у всех менеджеров было примерно одинаковое количество заявок за период.

Впервые решаю подобную задачу. И максимум, что мне приходит в голову, это:

рассчитать некий коэффициент распределения заявок на каждого менеджера из следующих данных:

1) количество заявок на каждого менеджера за период;

2) дата-время последней полученной менеджером заявки

Пункт 2 нужен, чтобы Вася, получивший 50 заявок 3 недели назад и все их выполнивший к сегодняшнему дню, не сидел без дела из-за того, что  Маша пришла к нам работать всего 10 дней назад и у нее было только 7 заявок за это время.

Факт выполнения заявки нигде никак не учитывается (специфика работы такая - отдал заявку и забыл).

Как обычно это делается? Наверняка, задача типовая.
Буду крайне благодарна за помощь. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Не нашла понятного для себя. Даже не знаю, как запрос сформулировать правильно. Буду благодарна за ссылку (можно в личку)

Comment: Вообще это вариант задачи о назначениях. Но в данных условиях можно просто каждый раз искать свободного менеджера с минимальным числом выполненных заявок за месяц. Либо назначать их по кругу

Comment: Может брать менеджера с самым старым временем последней заявки ? Не понятно зачем при наличии 2 условия, нужно первое. Если всегда брать того у кого наиболее долго не было заявок, то все менеджеры будут идти по кругу и всегда получать равномерное количество

Comment: Два условия нужны именно для того, чтобы распределять заявки равномерно всем менеджерам в единицу времени - и в месяц, и в 3 дня. Тут фокус в том, что кто-то из менеджеров работает давно, в кто-то недавно. Возможны ситуации, когда Маша со стажем работы 10 дней получила в обработку 7 заявок за это время, а Вася за последние 10 дней не получал ничего, т.к. ранее "перевыполнил план получения заявок", ибо, допустим, работал один и все заявки шли на него.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за комментарии выше! Сузив для простоты временной интервал до недели, я примерно вот, что с вашей помощью придумала.

Видимо, следует ввести 3 коэффициента:

К1 = Количество заявок за текущий день на конкретного менеджера;

К3 = Количество заявок за последние 3 дня на конкретного менеджера;

К7 = Количество заявок за последнюю неделю на конкретного менеджера;

Тогда алгоритм распределения будет примерно таким:

1. Выбираем менеджеров с минимальным К7;
2. Если среди К7 есть одинаковые, то из них выбираем менеджеров с минимальным К3;
3. Если среди К3 есть одинаковые, то выбираем, соответственно, менеджеров с минимальным К1.

По этому алгоритму я, наверное, и буду писать скрипт выбора.
Если что-то неправильно, подскажите, как правильно.